# AngularJS: ng-click for ng-repeat to get all data at once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my simple ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
    <h4>{{x.productid}}</h4>
    <h4>{{x.newquantity}}</h4>
    <h4>{{x.total}}</h4>
    <button ng-click="addInfoAboutOrder(x)">Add Info</button>
</div>
```

and AngularJS function:

```
$scope.addInfoAboutOrder = function(x) {
        $scope.productId = x.productid;
        $scope.productQuantity = x.newquantity;
        $scope.total = x.total;

        $http.post("api/setOrdersInfo" + "/" + $scope.productId + "/" + $scope.productQuantity + "/" + $scope.total)

    }
```

At the moment it is working. However, ng-repeat prints out button as many times as there are data(from 1 to 50). Of course this can be done by adding a simple filter, but it does not solve my problem. The biggest problem is it adds only one row in the table in the database. My problem is I can't make one

```
<button ng-click="addInfoAboutOrder(x)">Add Info</button>
```

to handle all my data in ng-repeat. I would like by one button click to add as many data in database as there are in ng-repeat.

Comment: where does the data for `names` come from?

Comment: It comes from: 
$http.get("api/getShoppingCart").success(function(response) {
      $scope.names = response;
      }); 
This information is stored in database.

Comment: You want to update all at ones and also one at a time?

Comment: That is rather what I had expected. I I can't see what you are trying to achieve if the data is already in the database why are you trying to  add it to the database

Comment: @SimonH Might be a separate table.

Comment: It's a web store. ng-repeat="x in names" prints out all items/products from a database. User's have possibility to make orders, in such case I would like to store information about order(item/product id, quantity, sum, etc.) in my database. I think it is logical. :) Of course I store information in separate tables. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the button outside of the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names">
  <h4>{{x.productid}}</h4>
  <h4>{{x.newquantity}}</h4>
  <h4>{{x.total}}</h4>
</div>
<button ng-click="addInfoAboutOrder(names)">Add Info</button>
```

Then pass in `names` instead of `x` and iterate over `names` in order to get all the data out of it, making a `$http` request for each iteration (do note that this will most likely cause performance issues for large data sets, so you should try to find a better solution to do what you want):

```
$scope.addInfoAboutOrder = function(names) {

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

       $http.post("api/setOrdersInfo" + "/" + names[i].productid + "/" + names[i].newquantity + "/" + names[i].total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect! :)